# rearrange a file contents in n number of columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a file with contents as :

```
        000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000001f000000
01000000060000000000000034000000
3f000000000000000000000004000000
000000001b0000000900000000000000
00000000600300001000000009000000
010000000400000008000000
```

i want to rearrange its contents by specifying the number of col's. for eg., if i say the no of col's to be 80, the output should be like :

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1f000000010000000600000000000000340000003f00000000000000000000000400000000000000
1b000000090000000000000000000000600300001000000009000000010000000400000008000000
```

can anyone help me with this ? can xxd serve the purpose here ? thanks.

Comment: @dwalter Why did you remove the C tag?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : i was trying using xxd -ps -c .....seems its not possible using xxd

Comment: @acraig5075: since the question in no way asked for c code but mostly how to solve this problem using linux/unix tools and bash or any other shell. (indicated by asking if xxd could help).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`tr`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tr%201) to first remove the whitespaces from the content, then use [`fold`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ufold.htm) to wrap them at a specific line width.

```
cat infile.txt | tr -d "[:space:]" | fold -80
```

Comment: You're welcome. `xxd` is designed to generate a hexdump, so while it does go folding of text it may not be the most suitable tool for this task.

Answer (score 1):

And as the question is also tagged C, here is a C way of doing the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    int c, col;

    fp = fopen("datafile.txt", "r");

    col = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') // ignore spaces and newline
            continue;

        putchar(c); // output to stdout
        ++col;

        if (col == 80) // newline at column 80
        {
            putchar('\n');
            col = 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to think that `10` somehow equals something you call "crlf", to end the line. This is a bit confused; 10 is the ASCII code for the line feed character, the "lf". Carriage return ("cr") is 13. Both are *much* better written as `'\n'` and `'\r'`, respectively, in C. You should never hardcode ASCII numbers. For a text output stream, just printing `'\n'` should suffice.

Comment: @unwind You're absolutely right, thank you, edited accordingly.